# How to implement onTouchEvent with a FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, touch-event, android-fragmentactivity

**My Question:** Is there a work-around for using an onTouchEvent in a FragmentActivity?

**My Situation:** I'm writing a simple flashlight app and I have a FragmentActivity where a user can swipe between colors (the whole screen is just one color. This app is for personal improvement). I want to be able to do a `onLongPress` event for options, a `onDoubleTap` event for hiding the navigation bar, and *most importantly* a touch event to control brightness of the app (I want to let the user scroll up and down for brightness changes, any ideas here are welcome! is the `onFling` event good for this?)

**What I've tried:** I have a `GestureDetector` with my implementation of an `SimpleOnGestureListener`. I override the `onTouchEvent` in the `FragmentActivity`, but I have just found out that this method is never called in a `FragmentActivity` (I also tested this with a `Log.print` in the method and it's never called). Is there a work-around? Thanks!

**Salient Code:**

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
  private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;

  /**
   * Called when the activity is first created.
   */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getApplicationContext(), new MyGestureListener(getWindow()));

    mAdapter = new ColorFragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getDefaultColorList());
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(Math.round(mAdapter.getCount() / 2)); //Set current fragment to middle fragment
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    print("Sending touch event to gestureDetector.");
    //This line is never run.
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
  }

  /**
   * Prints the given object to the log with the debug priority with the tag FLASHLIGHT
   *
   * @param object
   */
  public static void print(Object object) {
    Log.println(Log.DEBUG, "FLASHLIGHT", object.toString());
  }
}
```

MyGestureListener :

```
public class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

  private final Window window;

  public MyGestureListener(Window window) {
    super();
    this.window = window;
  }

  @Override
  public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    //onLongPress code
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    //onDoubleTap code
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    //onFling cod
  }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I don't think you'd need anything else to answer the question, but let me know if you do.

Comment: Can you please share the code and the layout for the project?

Comment: The missing touch events from the activity are most likely happeing because of the `ViewPager` and/or the fragments in the `ViewPager`. The `onTouchEvent` method of the `Activity` will be called only if the views in it didn't handle the touch event. Also, if I'm not mistaken you should also implement `onDown` in the `SimpleGestureListener` to return `true`.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this @Luksprog?

Comment: Did you also implement the `onDown` method in the gesture listener? What do you have in those fragments? Any touch events listeners in there?

Comment: @Luksprog, no. The fragments just override the `onCreateView` method. I don't implement `onDown`. Should I?

Comment: Implement the `onDown` method to return `true` and see how it goes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18741/discussion-between-kentcdodds-and-luksprog)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So the solution to this is relatively easy. The problem is that the ViewPager is eating the touch event. So what I did was write my own implementation of a ViewPager and overrided the `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` method by calling `super.onTouchEvent(event)` and then passing the event to the gestureDetector within the class.

**Relevant Code:**

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  private FragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);
    mAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    MyViewPager pager = (MyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureListener(this)));
    pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    pager.setCurrentItem(Math.round(mAdapter.getCount() / 2));
  }
}
```

MyViewPager

```
public class MyViewPager extends ViewPager {

  private GestureDetector gestureDetector;

  public MyViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public MyViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(e) && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
  }
}
```

MyGestureListener

```
public class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

  private final Activity activity;

  public MyGestureListener(Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
    //...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    //...
  }

//... etc...

}
```

layout_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
>
  <com.kentcdodds.flashlight.MyViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try doing this:

```
gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this);
```

and on the TouchEvent this:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(me);
}
```

[Source](http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener)

Comment: That's a little out dated. The constructor for the GestureDetector now takes a SimpleOnGestureListener as a second parameter. Also, the problem is that the `onTouchEvent` method that I'm overriding in the activity (and which you are referencing) is never called. Your answer will not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to simply detect when a user touches on the fragmentActivity use the following method:

```
public void onUserInteraction(){
  Log.d("FragmentActivity","touched");
}
```

More info at : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html